# Rotating object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two objects in scene..One is Cylinder and other is cube. How to rotate cube around the Cylinder..But the end towards the cylinder should not move from that place..Note that the cylinder is static and will not rotate..they are two different objects..And the cube will rotate around to right or left according to given input..

I have used

```
transform.RotateAround(Stable.transform.position, new Vector3(0, 10, 0), 90);
```

but it misplaces the cube from its location and apply 90 degree rotation

[image: Scene image]

Comment: The simpliest solution would be to place an empty GameObject to the same position where the cylinder is placed. Make the cube a child of that empty object and move it to it's start position. Then you could simply rotate the empty object instead and the cube would move along with it as I guess you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LookAt() function to have your cube look at your cylinder. You can then use Translate() to move it sideways.

```
Void Update(){
    transform.LookAt(target);
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime);
}
```